# Observation deleted due to missingness in R

Tags: r, regression

I am busy with a regression model in R and I have about 16 000 observations. One of these observations causes me to get the following error message:

```
# (1 observation deleted due to missingness)
```

Is there a way in R to identify this one observation?

Comment: Do you have missing values?

Comment: You can check if you have missing values in your data with `sum(is.na(variable))`. With `which(is.na(variable))` you can actually identify the index (indices) of your missing observation(s).

Comment: Try `which(apply(data, 1, function(x) any(is.na(x))))` to identify the row.

Comment: @lukeA Or `which(! complete.cases(x))`.

Comment: @KonradRudolph much better! :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If your data is in a data.frame `x`, and each row corresponds to an observation, then the way to go about this is to identify complete cases via `complete.cases(x)`. Conversely, to find missing values in an observation, do `! complete.cases(x)`. To find out *which* observation contains missing values, do

```
which(! complete.cases(x))
```

Comment: complete.cases worked. to identify the observation. Apparently it pulled the empty row from the csv file that was after the last observation.

Answer (score 2):

1 - Give your model a name like for example `MyModel`:

```
MyModel <- glm (......)
```

2 - Get the deleted observations rank by `na.action` function:

```
na.action(MyModel)
```

Results are duplicated in the display

Answer (score 0):

There is MWE as well as a solution in this web page : https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2010-February/227526.html

`which(is.na(variable))` as commented by @PeterDee seems to be indeed the solution