# Why does R deletes completed (not missing) information using svyglm?

Tags: r

I am using a data set with no missing information. Nevertheless when I fit a Poisson model using svyglm the output says: "14106 observations deleted due to missingness".

I checked one by one all my variables (those in the model and those in the svydesign object) and they all have complete data.

Do you have any idea about what is happening here?

I also tried defining the design as a SRS, but the output was exactly the same.

Here is the piece of code:

```
> sd<-svydesign(~db$V021, weights=db$V005d, data=db,  nest=TRUE)
> sd
1 - level Cluster Sampling design (with replacement)
With (4727) clusters.
svydesign(~db$V021, weights = db$V005d, data = db, nest = TRUE)
> f1<-BIRTH ~DEPTO+GPARI+V012+CONST+MARIT+YEDU+WORK+YEARC+s3V+MIG
> mr1<-svyglm(f1, family=poisson, offset=log(PYL1),subset=lciti,design=sd)
> mr1
1 - level Cluster Sampling design (with replacement)
With (673) clusters.
svydesign(~db$V021, weights = db$V005d, data = db, nest = TRUE)

Call:  svyglm(formula = f1, family = poisson, offset = log(PYL1), subset = lciti, 
    design = sd)

Coefficients:
    (Intercept)          DEPTO08          DEPTO11          DEPTO13          DEPTO15  
       -0.73230          0.61040          0.35365          0.69421          0.44212  
        DEPTO17          DEPTO19          DEPTO20          DEPTO41          DEPTO47  
        0.67622          0.84396          0.60027          0.70733          0.68330  
        DEPTO50          DEPTO54          DEPTO63          DEPTO66          DEPTO68  
       -0.23165          0.55535         -0.52875          0.40425          0.35383  
        DEPTO70          DEPTO73          DEPTO76          DEPTO18          DEPTO44  
        0.74401          3.11368          0.24281          0.44820          1.01582  
        DEPTO88         GPARIOne         GPARITwo       GPARIThree       GPARI>Four  
        0.37261         -1.01677         -1.85703         -2.53115         -2.56539  
           V012       CONSTNever  CONSTNon-modern  CONSTSterilized      MARITSingle  
       -0.01859         -1.16046         -0.06644          0.47375         -0.71028  
MARITMarried/LT      MARITNot LT             YEDU       WORKUnpaid     WORKUnstable  
        1.06032          0.55939         -0.06660          0.14973         -0.08110  
     WORKStable        YEARC2005        YEARC2010       s3VViolent          MIGBorn  
       -0.63613         -0.40439         -0.01301          0.14730          0.11877  

Degrees of Freedom: 5234 Total (i.e. Null);  633 Residual
  (14106 observations deleted due to missingness)
Null Deviance:      2885 
Residual Deviance: 2237     AIC: 3635
```

Comment: I would double check missing obs with `which(! complete.cases(db))` related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28429055/observation-deleted-due-to-missingness-in-r

Comment: Thanks @Amstell I did it, but still removing thousands of observations.

> which(!complete.cases(db))
integer(0)

Comment: Without looking at your data, it's hard to know exactly.  Did you check the min and max values to verify they are in a range and not constant?  I'd take a look around the data set if it were me.  Something is not working well with the model.